# Would it make sense to build an open source project around a paid AWS service?

Tags: website, freeware

I'm thinking of creating a web app (details of which I'll give later) with the intention of participating in a hackathon hosted by Hashnode in conjunction with AWS Amplify (link: https://townhall.hashnode.com/aws-amplify-hackathon), and the app is kind of required to be open source, which I would really love to do. But at the same time, I want to create a business out of it (if possible).

I've been thinking rigorously about what the best way to go about this would be, but I don't seem to have figured it out.

The app I want to create is one that lets people create text tutorials/courses (not videos) in which people can enroll as students. I don't even know if this is a good idea, but I'm willing to do it. I came up with it when I wanted to create such a course myself but found no tool for it (some months ago). The app would include some features like chapter questions, e.t.c.

The problem now is that the app must be open source, and I want to do business out of it. After pondering the situation, I thought it would be good if I used the model used by Automattic with WordPress, or Ghost with the open-source Ghost software. I would make the core of the software open source while creating a business by offering a one-click setup of the software on my own servers.

But based on the requirements (of the hackathon), AWS Amplify must be used. I must therefore build the core of the software with the platform, at least for purposes of the hackathon.

My question now is: do you think it would be a good thing to build the core of such software around AWS Amplify (a paid service)?

The users (developers) would be able to self-host the software on their own servers but have to use AWS Amplify to enable authentication, storage, e.t.c. This sort of thing is very common (as far as I know). Open source software like that usually uses an open source database and other open source backend software too. Ghost and WordPress are examples. They both use MySQL.

Maybe I would have to build the software such that people who decide to self-host it would be able to use different backend platforms/software instead of just AWS Amplify.

Comment: I don't believe this is a question which has or even can have a clear answer and as such is subject to opinion. You basically laid out many the pros and cons already yourself. Mind though that open source does not mean you need to disclose all later versions, if you use a permissive license. There is no such requirement in any case if you are the sole author or don't distribute the software (like often done for SAAS).

Comment: With respect, I rather agree with planetmaker.  You say "*I must use AWS Amplify*", then ask if it's a good idea to use AWS Amplify.  I'm not sure what sort of answer you're expecting to get.

Comment: I'm sorry for not laying it out well. I was trying to ask if it is possible to build a project around a paid service like AWS Amplify, and still get contributions.

I want the project to receive contributions, but having to build it around AWS Amplify seems to make that impossible.

Maybe I'll just build the first version that way, and find ways to make it work with other databases and backend platforms after that.